# Can I use an alias to release a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to release a Chrome Extension but am not certain whether I would like to do it under my name. Is there a way to release it using an alias without creating a separate Google account?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In the developer's dashboard you can decide which name you want to be displayed, and you can use an alias.

Comment: as a recommendation based on what I did with my chrome extension: get a google apps domain with one user. its just $50 a year and you can then pick a nice domain and email for users to see, like"support@myapp.com" which is an alias to admin@myapp.com. In contrast, Gmail aliases must prepend your real email name, as in john+myapp@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

> You can decide on the display name in the developer dashboard.

Therefore, it is possible to use an alias.

[image]